# Cleaning and maintenance?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The [cleaning](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) and [maintenance](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tags are both used for cleaning, and both used for maintenance. It seems the only reason for this is that the site doesn't know they are similar, and doesn't suggest them.

I propose that [cleaning](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) be made a synonym of [maintenance](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance).

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the [maintenance](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag covers topics like cleaning and more.  I say instead of making them synonyms just remove [cleaning](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) and expand the description of the [maintenance](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) tag to explain the broad scope of this tag.

Comment: I think people will still use [tag:cleaning] though :-/ Which is why I proposed the synonym as opposed to deletion.

Comment: Just because people will use the wrong tag doesn't mean it should be deleted.  Remove the word 'cleaning' from the maintenance tag wiki, expand both wikis, and keep both tags separate.

Comment: @Chenmunka But then we'd have to unmix all of the badly tagged questions.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the questions, I think it is best to create a tag-synonym, as people are still using the tags interchangeably. If this is not disputed, I will super-vote the proposal and create the synonym.